# Html to SVG string

Tags: html, canvas, svg, internet-explorer-8, html2canvas

Does anyone know of a way to convert a section of an HTML page by passing a div to convert to SVG string?

I am currently exporting all Highcharts charts into SVG and passing them to an web service to save to a word document.  I also need datatables and other sections displayed on an HTML page to export into powerpoint?

Ideally this would need to work in IE 8 too.

Thanks

Comment: You could just include the HTML in the SVG using `foreignObject`

Comment: Thanks, however that wont work if there is classes involved.  Ideally i want a screenshot of the HTML

Comment: Maybe then this is, what you are looking for: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Thanks, however, that wont work in IE 8

Comment: You cannot use ie8 to snapshot the browser window in any case so either forget the idea that it need to work in ie8 with javascript and canvas/svg (it won't), or use external software like snagit etc. to do the snapshots. It's just the reality. Sirko's suggestion(s) is the closest thing.

Comment: Ok thanks all, I will have to opt out of IE8.  Looking at the HTML2Canvas, is there a way to get the svg string out?

Comment: Html2Canvas doesn't produce a SVG but a canvas (bitmap). Ref. the name. We are only in 2014, why should things be easy.. :) But in a serious light: there are a some potential security risks involving images which is the main reason why this is not so easy as one should think it would be. To get around you have to be willing to do some compromises.